# R wordcloud2 letterCloud showing only the background

Tags: r, word-cloud

My Rstudio version is 3.4.1 64-bit on Win10. I have installed the package `wordcloud2` via the commands

```
install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github("lchiffon/wordcloud2")
```

And things went smoothly. Then I tried running the example from the official documentation on R console:

```
letterCloud(demoFreq, word='R')
```

Then what comes up is only the background colour, and nothing else at all. Web browser is Chrome 59.0 64-bit. However, the other function `wordcloud` works quite well.

I suppose this should be a common problem, so hopefully somebody can give me some help, thanks.

Comment: That's weird, I can confirm your code does not work. But when I run the exemple from the help, `letterCloud(demoFreq,"R")`, it did work. Then your code worked. There is something odd to find.

Comment: @YCR unfortunately neither worked for me.

Comment: I got mixed result also, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I got a 'ReferenceError: iii is not defined' in the JS console, so the problem seems  to originate in the `htmlwidget` part

Comment: I get the following warning also the first time I run the code: `Warning message:
In sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) :
  '.Random.seed' is not an integer vector but of type 'NULL', so ignored` The second time, the code works, though.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is already raised here: https://github.com/Lchiffon/wordcloud2/issues/12.

Unfortunately, no solution is yet on the table other than refreshing your window.

Also, IE and Firefox seems to work better than chrome.

Comment: You mean refreshing the page in the browser? Does it really work?

Comment: Not in the browser, in the Viewer windows of rstudio. It works for me.

Comment: is it the subwindow prompted by the `letterCloud` command? Also, how to change the browser in which the image is to be shown? Do I have to change the system default browser?

Comment: [Here](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7221728/21085444/2d2a5346-c04d-11e6-832f-7772361ce57d.png) this is the viewer tab.You can use the top right icon to refresh the windows and the center icon to open the graph in a browser. From the moment you have the url (stg like localhost::...) you can open it in any browser.

Comment: Hum... unless you use another IDE than rstudio (like vim) and in that case, it may be different.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can now reinstall it from GitHub using:

```
devtools::install_github("lchiffon/wordcloud2")
```

and it works well. :)

Comment: You mean it's fixed? The issue linked in the other answer is still open.

Comment: I know, i had the same issue but after reinstalling it from GitHub, it works.

Comment: I had the bug when installed from CRAN. installation from github works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing works in my case. But sometimes when I try to save the image, the figure again disappears and doesn't appear again until I restart.

Comment: it's a comment, but not an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have found changing the size of the font the best solution. If the fonts are too large for the margins of your shape it will not populate. Then hit refresh a couple of times.

Edited to add: what I think is going on is that when the Word Cloud is populating the words have to fit into the margins. So if some of them do not fit it stops. SO refreshing rearranges the word pattern.
I make sure that I install these libraries along with wordcoud2

```
library("glue")
library("usethis")
library("htmltools")
library("rlang")
library("tm")
library("SnowballC")

library("usethis")
library("htmltools")
library("NLP")
library("tm")
library("RColorBrewer")
library("SnowballC")
library("wordcloud")
library("RColorBrewer")
library("pdftools")
library("plotly")
library("tidyverse")
library("jsonlite")
library("devtools")
devtools::install_github("lchiffon/wordcloud2", force=TRUE)
library("wordcloud2")
```